# Check xml node is exist or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to check given node is exist or not in `*.xml` file.
I try:

```
 string language = node.SelectSingleNode("language") != null ? (node.SelectSingleNode("language").Value == "en" ? "en-US" : "en-US") : "en-US";
```

But I think its check only for node value.In some `xml` file I haven't node called `language` So its gives a  `Null Reference Ex..`.
How to check Given node is exist or not in `*.xml` file? Thanks.

Comment: Result is always "en-US", so `string language = "en-US"` does the same!

Comment: The only way I can see that code would throw a NullReferenceException would be if `node` itself were null. Please can you confirm that is your **exact** code, that node is not null, and that it's definitely this line of code that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something is `null`. You are checking the selected "language" node for `null`, so is `node` itself `null`?

Spread the code out over more lines, nested `?:` code is not easy to follow and you have had to repeat default values and function calls.

Use variables, such as one for `node.SelectSingleNode("language")` so you don't do that twice. And this will help you find the bug.

```
string language = "en-US"; //default
if(node!=null)
{
  var langNode = node.SelectSingleNode("language");
  if(langNode!=null)
  {
    //now look at langNode.Value, and overwrite language variable, maybe you wanted:
    if(langNode.Value != "en")
    {
       language = langNode.Value;
    }
  }
}
```