# How to check if element exists in this xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this problem to programming it. For each specific port element I want check if `<script>` exixst. The `<script>` is a child of `<port>` node element. Take this example, here's a link to the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2FGr.png

```
 // Leggi il file xml

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(pathFile.Text);



        var hosts = from h in xml.Descendants("address")
                   select new
                   {
                       addr = h.Attribute("addr").Value,
                       addrtype = h.Attribute("addrtype").Value
                   };

        foreach (var host in hosts)
        {
            if (host.addrtype == "ipv4")
            {
                console.Text += host.addr + Environment.NewLine;
                console.Text += host.addrtype + Environment.NewLine;

                var ports = xml.Descendants("port");

                foreach (var port in ports)
                {
                    var script = port.Element("script");

                    var hasScriptElement = script != null;

                    ?? -> how can i get the elem pem key value? thanks!!
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Cris please post some piece of your code. It quite difficult to help you without it

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004903/check-xml-node-is-exist-or-not

Comment: Show us some example xml. Put all the text we need to know **here in the question**, not in an image off-site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `XDocument`...

```
var ports = document.Descendants("port");

foreach (var port in ports) {
    var script = port.Element("script");

    if (script != null)
    {
        var pem = script.Descendants("elem")
            .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Attribute("pem") != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehm thanks and how can i get the elem key="pem" ? value? Thanks!

Comment: Is that where the port has that attribute or where the script has that attribute?

Comment: @SteveFenton, see picture.

Comment: @SteveFenton ehm yes the script has other elements and i would get the elem with key="pem". Thanks very much for 1° help!

Comment: I have added that to the example for you. You should be able to use `Descendants`, `Element` and Linq to get pretty much anything based on these examples.

Comment: Thanks to Steve Fenton the best helper!

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer:

- find `<port` and then `>`
- find `</port>`
- if between is a `<script`, then you have script

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are trying to ask or point out. Do you mean, what my answer doesn't answer on a question on a picture (how to get `<pem>` value)? Or do you mean what `<script` can be inside comments. Or what? =D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using an [XML Schema (XSD)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema) and validate your XML against it. This should be considered as **best practice**!

You can found a guide how to [validate your XML against an XSD programatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a console app that demonstrates how this could be done:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = "c:\path\to\file\test.xml";
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(File.OpenRead(fileName));
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("port");
        XmlNodeReader nodeReader;
        foreach (var node in nodeList)
        {
            using(nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader((XmlNode)node))
            {
                if(nodeReader.ReadToDescendant("script"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found script tag");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```